# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat

Tags: macos, hadoop, sqoop

I am doing sqoop import in MAC OSX 10.9.4  and getting error as:

```
14/10/24 11:51:41 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5
14/10/24 11:51:41 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
14/10/24 11:51:41 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
14/10/24 11:51:41 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
14/10/24 11:51:41 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/10/24 11:51:42 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `test_log` AS t LIMIT 1
14/10/24 11:51:42 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `test_log` AS t LIMIT 1
14/10/24 11:51:42 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/2398ed5be0489f1c76d6fb556f3e0e9d/test_log.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/10/24 11:51:45 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/2398ed5be0489f1c76d6fb556f3e0e9d/test_log.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ImportJobContext.<init>(ImportJobContext.java:51)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.ImportJobContext.<init>(ImportJobContext.java:33)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:483)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 58 more
```

Hadoop version : 2.5.1
Sqoop  version  :1.4.5
os :         OSX10.9.4

env varibles are set:

> export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/
>
> export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/
>
> Sqoop jar (sqoop-1.4.5.jar) is placed in /Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/lib/
> and mysql connector in /Users/hadoop/sqoop/lib

also the core.jar exist in

> /Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the Jars were not accessible. After puting the Sqoop jars in HDFS, Sqoop import went fine.
This link helped 
[Sqoop jar files not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375784/sqoop-jar-files-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in ${HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME}/*.jar; do
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:$f;
done
```

add this to bin/configure-sqoop

Answer (score 1):

cd $SQOOP_HOME/bin

vim configure-sqoop

add below line

```
add_to_classpath ${HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME}
```

after "add_to_classpath ${SQOOP_JAR_DIR}"

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your if in your $HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR you can find the library.
If not you can put it in the same dir of your mapreduce implementation:

/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/

Comment: InputFromat.class exit in    

/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar

Have tried  editing sqoop-env.sh with... 

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/etc/hadoop
and
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce 

also but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ! Just copy hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into the lib folder from sqooq. Dirty but it works. You probably just want to make some tests