# Sqoop import from Oracle failed with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop, hadoop2

When trying to import data from Oracle to Hadoop using Sqoop, it it failing with the error `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat"`

Gone through with this [Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542874/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-inputfo). But, those did not solved my issue.

Command used as below.

```
sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts='-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom' --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/servicename --username XXXXX --password XXXXX   --hadoop-mapred-home /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce --table DB.STUDENTS --verbose --target-dir /user/1234/out -m 1
```

And below is the part of the log where I am getting the error.

```
18/08/10 03:42:48 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-user1234/compile/115556141b1ea2b78ea960493a789953/DB1.STUDENTS.jar
18/08/10 03:42:48 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Scanning for .class files in directory: /tmp/sqoop-user1234/compile/115556141b1ea2b78ea960493a789953
18/08/10 03:42:48 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Got classfile: /tmp/sqoop-user1234/compile/115556141b1ea2b78ea960493a789953/DB1_STUDENTS.class -> DB1_STUDENTS.class
18/08/10 03:42:48 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Finished writing jar file /tmp/sqoop-user1234/compile/115556141b1ea2b78ea960493a789953/DB1.STUDENTS.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

This class `org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat`  is available in jar `/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0-cdh5.7.1.jar` and variable(`export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce)` is set with this path.

And this how below variables are configured.

```
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/conf/hadoop_dev
```