# Sqoop import cannot locate needed JDBC file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sqoop

Ok, someone has already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375784/sqoop-jar-files-not-found#_=_) question once, but it seems that didn't help, so here is my question.

I've got Hadoop 2.5.1 installed on my Cent OS 7 machine. It's set up to run in a pseudo distributed mode. I ran few MapReduce sample jobs - so assume that all the configuration is fine.

I've downloaded Sqoop 1.4.5. And installed MySql database (MariaDB) and created the needed table.

NOW. I'm running the following command:

```
  bin/sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoopdb \
   --table sqooptable --export-dir /user/dennis \
   --fields-terminated-by '\t' --username root --password ***
```

It returns the following error message:

> 14/11/12 06:11:54 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException
> running export job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not
> exist:
> hdfs://localhost:9000/home/dennis/Sqoop/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar

The file mentioned in the error doest exist in the local file system, moreover I've given it chmod 777 - just so that everyone was able to access it.

Any ideas anyone please?

The way i understand it - it looks for the mentioned file somewhere in hdfs whereas it is located in the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work. It is definitely the worst solution possible - but noone had offered me anything better. I've created the folder structure in the HDFS and copied the bloody JAR there. Now you can judge me :) [The same thing written on my blog](http://datawithdennis.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/sqoop-1-4-5-installation/)