# sqoop: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat

Tags: java, sqoop

I am trying to import mySQL data to HDFS using sqoop.

My environment is:
Ubuntu 16.04
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.16.1
Sqoop 1.4.7

On executing
    `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/crawl_data_stats --username root --password password --table auth_group`

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)  
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)  
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at [Sqoop jar files not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375784/sqoop-jar-files-not-found) and copied hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar to /usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/ and the error got resolved